# fixed header goes up side when click on text box

Tags: iphone, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

i  am creating phonegap app using mobile jquery 1.3.2. everything is ok but when fill  form  click on text box header not showing.  div position change when keypad open and header go on top that not show.

I want to show header on top of screen and alyase show

Comment: how did you fixed the headers? i had the same problem but that was because i had done it with css instead of putting data-position="fixed" attribute.After put that solved my problem.